# Laravel 5 pagination

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I made pagination like in guides.I doing a search in db, and refer variable with data ti view.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $products = DB::table('product')->where('number', 'like', $request->number.'%')->paginate(5);
    return view('site.content_layouts', [
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}
```

Here is part of my html file

```
 @foreach($products as $product)
                <form role="form" method="get" action="{{ route('add_to_cart') }}">
                <tr>
                    <input type="hidden" name = "id" value="{{$product->id}}">

                    <td>{{$product->manufacturer}}</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name = "manufacturer" value="{{$product->manufacturer}}">

                    <td>{{$product->number}}</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name = "number" value="{{$product->number}}">

                    <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name = "name" value="{{$product->name}}">

                    <td>{{$product->quantity}}</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name = "quantity" value="{{$product->quantity}}">

                    <td>{{$product->incoming_time}}</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name = "trader" value="{{$product->trader}}">

                    <td>{{$product->price}}</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name = "price" value="{{$product->price}}">

                    <td><input size="5px" type="text"  id="quantity_choose" name="quantity_choose" value="1"></td>

                    <td>
                        <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="AddToCart">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="AddToCart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddToCart" >
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">

                                </span>
                                </button>
                        </p>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                </form>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>{{$products->links()}}
```

First page displayed normally. But when I follow the links of other pages, there displayed first 5 lines of ALL my db, and created links to 61k pages.Not only  lines what I search like in first page - its deduces all my db. Help me please) Where is a problem?

[1)First page, where al is normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9qkb.png)
[2)Here I use link of second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1nIs.png)

Comment: Does page 2 still have `$request->number` in the URL?

Comment: How do you request page number in pagination?

Comment: its url of 1 page - h ttp://shop/search?_token=hqmlTOxVeGnY3kbfpYPz0GPFyiMjNeiemvOIY2TY&number=j1

its url of 2+ pages - http://shop/search?page=2

Comment: @PankajMakwana I have a input form , where I put request number .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `appends()` if your pagination has extra parameters. It will add more GET parameters to your url so the search queries will be passed to `$request` in second page . Refer [detail here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#displaying-pagination-results).

Your code should look similarly like below.

```
$products = DB::table('product')->where('number', 'like', $request->number.'%')->paginate(5)->appends($request->all());
```

Above code will carry all parameters passed to the `$request`.